# Using dirent->d_name together with string fails

Tags: c++, directory, dirent.h

I'm writing an C++ Application that uses the `dirent.h` library, to read files from a directory. At one point I want to decide between Files and directories. To achieve that I added the following piece of code:

```
entry = readdir(used_directory); //read next object from directory stream
DIR* directory_test = opendir((path + entry->d_name).c_str()); //try to open object as directory
if ( directory_test != nullptr) { //object is directory
    if (entry != nullptr) { //reading from directory succeeded
        dirs.push_back(entry->d_name); //add filename to file list
        ++dircounter;
    }
}
else { //object is file
```

`path` is type of `string` and entry is type of `dirent *`. 
With this, the program causes an memory access error, without it doesn't.
I figured out, that the error is caused by the

```
(path + entry->d_name)
```

But it is not the implicit conversion to `string` in the statement, because other tests like `cout << entry->d_name;` or `path += entry->d_name` failed with the same error, too. So obviously there is a failure with using `entry->d_name` as `char *`, although it is defined so ([in the documentation of dirent.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/dirent.h.html)).
Why is this failure occuring?

**EDIT**:
Later in the program I add `entry->d_name` to a `vector<string>`, that doesn't cause any problems.

Comment: You're using `entry` before testing for `nullptr`, which is incorrect. Also, maybe using `stat()` is simpler?

Comment: @myaut Yes this was the failure! Than you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The failure was accessing entry before checking if it's equal to `nullptr`.
Because my loop itterating through the directory is stopped if entry is equal to `nullptr`, the last itteration causes the error.